# Using \autoref with bibliography references

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, autoref

I use `\autoref` with all of my figures, tables, etc. since I like the look and feel of the output, and also the ease of customisability (for instance, if I change my mind about how to reference figures).

Is there a way to include bibliography items into `\autoref`? For example, suppose I want to say something like: "A review on this topic can be found in Reference [10]", while still maintaining the look and feel of `\autoref`.

Comment: `\cite`? Or `\autocite` provided by `biblatex`?

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear... it has more to do with the way the citation is labelled. If I type \ref{fig}, it will print the figure number. But if I type \autoref{fig}, it will print "Figure x", or "Fig. x", or whatever I choose. My question is whether there is an equivalent command for citing?

Comment: Personlly, i consider it as extremely bad style to write *Have a look at reference [10]*, i advice against such practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though possible, i wouldn't do it.

[image: stefvonbBiblatexAutoref]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\newcommand{\aautocite}[1]{reference~\autocite{#1}}
\newcommand{\aautocites}{references~\autocites}
\begin{document}
Have a look at \aautocite{kastenholz} as well as
\aautocites{ctan,companion}[8]{markey}[3]{aristotle:physics}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

There might be ways to do it with `biblatex` directly.